# why does (nil) evaluate differently than ((println "foo"))

Tags: clojure

Why the discrepancy in the last two lines below? Evaluation exceptions are pasted from the REPL. I am using Clojure 1.4

```
(println "foo") ;; evals to nil

(nil)  ;; CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't call nil
((println "foo")) ;; NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One is a compile time exception; the other is a run-time exception.

In the case of `(nil)` the compiler sees your are trying to make a function call to `nil` and gives you a compile error.

In the case of `((println "foo"))` the compiler does not try to infer what the inner form `(println "foo")` will return. For all it knows it could return a function, so the check does not occur at compile time. The exception occurs at run-time when indeed `println` returns a `nil` and you attempt to call it.

Being a dynamic language means you don't generally try to detect type errors of variables at compile-time.

Observe:

```
(.setDynamic #'println)

(binding [println 
           (fn [x] 
             (when (pos? (rand-int 2)) 
               (fn [] (print "bar\n"))))] 
  ((println "foo")))
```

which will randomly either print "bar" and return `nil` with no run-time exception or print nothing and throw a run-time `NullPointerException`. Here it is clear this contrived `println` has no static return type for the compiler to detect.

But the compiler can still detect type errors involving only values.